# Network Client use wrong input devices when using Unity.Netcode with Starter Asset Controller (New input system)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

The server is always using Keyboard and Mouse just fine.

The client however always use "xbox controller" instead of Keyboard & Mouse:

The following is the inspector view as a client:

[image]

The Start Asset input action are unchanged,
[image]

This is what I tried but client is still being assigned to controller:

```
private void Start()
{
    if (!IsOwner)
    {
        Destroy(GetComponent<PlayerInput>());
    }
}
```

How could I fix this? Other than hard coding `(PlayerInput)map.SwitchCurrentControlScheme("KeyboardAndMouse");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed by disabling `Player Input` script.

And only enable it on Network Spawn.

```
    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        base.OnNetworkSpawn();
        if (IsOwner)
        {
            _playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
            _playerInput.enabled = true;
        }
    }
```